# Git push is pushing unwanted files from another project

Tags: git, github

I have a project and I create repository on GitHub. I do this by following the instructions on pushing an existing repository from the command line. I follow the exact same instructions on another project and now it pushes files from this project and files from the project before. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

the instructions I follow on pushing an existing respository from the command line:

```
git remote add origin <github url>
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Git will push whatever is on the revisions of the history of the branch you pushed... so the problem is not on the push operation.... the problem is that you messed up the history of the branch you are pushing.

Comment: So should i remove all remotes before pushing a new project to a repository, would that fix the problem in the future?

Comment: I think that the problem you are talking about (files from different projects being pushed) is not really related to remotes... it's about having added and committed files at the wrong moment or branch. Adding or deleting remotes won't make a difference.

Comment: How do I make sure I don't add files at the wrong moment or branch? It all works good until I try to push the repository to GitHub.

Comment: `git push` pushes *commits*, not files. Commits *contain* files (so the files come along for the ride) but you're always working with *commits* here.